# sjt.grpmean results inside sjPlot are not correctly displayed

Tags: r, sjplot

I have a problem with sjPlot command: sjt.grpmean

This is my example:

```
x <- rnorm(120,1230,220)
f <- c(rep("men",60),rep("women",60))
d <- data.frame(x,f)

library(sjPlot)

sjt.grpmean(var.cnt = d$x,
            var.grp = d$f)
```

The result is just weird.

I try this:

```
x <- rnorm(120,1230,220)
f <- as.factor(c(rep("men",60),rep("women",60)))
d <- data.frame(x,f)

library(sjPlot)
sjt.grpmean(var.cnt = d$x,d$f)
```

With same weird result.

I Can use this workaround:

```
sjt.grpmean(var.cnt = d$x,
            var.grp = d$f,
            value.labels = c("men","women"))
```

But, why  i need to use value.labels to fix?
is this a bug?

I will appreciate any help.

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)

sjPlot 2.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this a bug?

Yes, it's a bug you found. I have already fixed it in the current dev-version on GitHub, a CRAN-update may follow in March...

Comment: Thanks, i can't install the dev-version in my personal pc (i use it a lot for my job and using dev version create me problem with another package), but i will try the github in another pc.

Comment: Yes, the dev-version depends on my other packages. So, you first need to install sjmisc, than sjstats and finally sjPlot from GitHub. That should work.